# How to instanciate a custom class that extends MapFragment (which is singleton)

Tags: android, fragment, mapfragment

I need to create a custom class that extends `MapFragment`. I am not sure how to instantiatemy new class, so that MapFragment will be instantiated in the correct way.

MapFragment are suppose to be created by doing

```
MapFragment.newInstance(options)
```

If I have my own class, that extends MapFragment

```
public class MyMapFragment extends MapFragment {



}
```

How do I go about to instantiate `MyMapFragment`, or is this approach all together wrong?

Comment: An answer to the question "Set GoogleMapOptions for the MapFragment subclass" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24687803/262789) should provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you can accomplish what you need using the built in MapFragment (although it isn't clear WHY you want to subclass the fragment).

Use a standard MapFragment, use `map = mapFragment.getMap()` to access the underlying [`GoogleMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html), and use `map.setXXXListener` to catch events.

If you really need lower-level access for some reason, you are going to have to extend `Fragment` and build and manage a `GoogleMap` yourself.

Comment: I am looking to catch the onPause and onResume events so that I can make sure that the markers I've added are always visible.

Comment: I see. You can get those in the enclosing Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tried to do:

[ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object in a class extending MapFragment in onSaveInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612336/classnotfoundexception-reading-a-serializable-object-in-a-class-extending-mapfra)

But i got stuck at a point when i tried to save some data using onSaveInstanceState. If you dont want to store data to reuse it, the source code explains how i created the class and how it was loaded.