# Set GoogleMapOptions for the MapFragment subclass

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

There is a method

```
MapFragment.newInstance(options)
```

The problem is that I have my own CustomMapFragment which is subclass of MapFragment and I don't see how I can set GoogleMapOptions for a subclass.

I need this to set

> options.zOrderOnTop(true);

Is there any way to set map options without creating a new fragment or maybe I can change Z-order somehow else?

Comment: why not set pass a bundle to your newInstance() indicating that you want to zOrderOnTop()

Comment: I have the same issue except I need to set useViewLifecycleInFragment to true for my subclass, which can only be done with the Factory pattern. Artjom's answer is ugly, lots of code changes and not graceful, but I can't see a better way.

Comment: @RobP please look at my own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the correct solution was to look inside Android source code. After this I came up with this method:

```
public static CustomMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options) {
     CustomMapFragment f = new CustomMapFragment();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putParcelable(MAP_OPTIONS, options);
     f.setArguments(args);
     return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use composition instead of inheritance ([Composition vs inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) and come up with something like this:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {
    private MapFragment mapFragment; // google's map fragment

    public MyMapFragment() {
        this.mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    }

    public MyMapFragment(GoogleMapOptions options) {
        this.mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(options);
    }

    // delegate other methods to mapFragment
}
```

Comment: Is it really correct that instance and mapFragment are static? Wouldn't each instance of MyMapFragment need its own mapFragment?

Comment: You're right, it is not a good idea to build singleton in this case. I edited my answer.

Comment: Adding constructor other than a no arg one might not be a good idea. Although the system will be able to recreate your fragment in this case using the no arg constructor your MapFragment won't be setup with  the GoogleMapOptions used previously